# CocoaPods Google Analytics .xcworkspace and .xcodeproj files

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have an error in `.xcodeproj`:

> ld: framework not found Pods (null): Linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I found the mistake the pod install folder was good, but I have to build the `.xcworkspace`, but I don't know why they're the error on `.xcodeproj`, and if it can be a problem on application deployment someone know why they're the error ? How to hide this error ?

Comment: Did you open the project via .xcworkspace ?

Comment: You should go with `xcworkspace` and believe me there will be no problem in application deployment .

Comment: @OhadM no i'm working with .xcodeproj Xcode open it as default

Comment: @rptwsthi I have to work with .xcworkspace file on Xcode ?

Comment: Yep, once you started using cocoapod in you code, there is no escape from that.

Comment: @Ben welcome! Keep up good coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cocoapods states when you setup cocoapods in your projects the first time, you need to use xcworkspace from now on. You can't work on xcodeproj directly. This is because it needs to have both Pods and your app project open at the same time.

Just close your xcodeproj and never open it again. Always open the xcworkspace and always work from there as long as you are using cocoapods in your project.

Answer (score 4):

Follow this steps:

- Make sure **close** all `Xcode` Projects. (`.xcworkspace` and `.xcproject`) (sometimes `.xcproject` still open)
- **Run** `pod install` and `pod update`
- **Open** the `ProjectName.xcworkspace`
- **Clean** and **Build** your Project

After that you should be able to run normally.